# privilages system table in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to know all the tables a user has access to using a single query?

I tried with `pg_role` and `pg_user` with no luck. Can anyone tell me about a system table which has the data of all the objects that a user has access to?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a canned view for that purpose, but such a query is possible to write.

You'd have to query each object type independently, forming a big `UNION`. A number of [system information functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html) are available for checking permissions on objects, see [the *Access Privilege Inquiry Functions* table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-ACCESS-TABLE).

Combine them with queries over `information_schema`, or over the internal PostgreSQL tables like `pg_class`, `pg_proc`, etc, and you'll be able to collect the desired information.

You might find the queries `psql` uses to implement `\dp` and the various `+` commands like `\df+` informative. Run `psql` with `-E` to see them.